# How to add an entry in the Windows context menu for files with a specific extension?

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I know that many questions are asked about how customizing the shell context menu, but what I've tried yet doesn't work so I'm adding a new question.

I'd like to add an entry "Open with Log Viewer" in the context menu when right-clicking on files with ".log" extension, to not change the default application associated with .log files (notepad) but allow the user to choose a custom application to open them.

To do this, I opened the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.log`, and added some keys `shell\OpenWithLogViewer\command` with the correct values, but the entry is not displayed when I right-click on a file with .log extension.

Would you know how to fix this?

The key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.log` has for default value `txtfile`, and contains a subkey called `PersistentHandler`. Can this subkey be the origin of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add another registry key (e.g. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\logfile`), create the `shell` structure below that key and change the default value of the `.log` key to `logfile`. One way to do this is by saving the following lines to a `.reg` file and merging that file into the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.log]
@="logfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\logfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\logfile\shell]
@="OpenWithLogViewer"
; make OpenWithLogViewer the default action

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\logfile\shell\OpenWithLogViewer]
@="Open with &Log Viewer"
; set label and access key

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\logfile\shell\OpenWithLogViewer\command]
@="\"C:\\path\\to\\logviewer.exe\" %1"
```

This separates the type (`logfile`) from the extension (`.log`). That way you can define the possible actions for a type in one place and associate arbitrary extensions with that type.

Note that you can also define this on a per-user basis by using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. User entries take precedence over system entries. This is useful when you want to change file associations or add custom actions for your own user, but don't have admin privileges on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a entry for a file extension you don't "own" and you never want to be the default action then you can use the [SystemFileAssociations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872122(v=vs.85).aspx) key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.log\shell\mycommand]
@="My Command"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.log\shell\mycommand\command]
@="\"c:\\path\\myapp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

> To deal proactively with the consequences of a change to default programs, you can use HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations to register verbs and other association information. Due to their location after the ProgID in the association array, these registrations are lower priority. These SystemFileAssociationsregistrations are stable even when users change the default programs, and provide a location to register secondary verbs that will always be available for a particular file type.

This key is available on Windows XP and higher...