# File Name be the c++ input from the right click menu

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, windows-xp

I am trying to code a program with c++ that adds a link to the right click menu when you select a file and when the user clicks on it , the program will open and i want the input to be the filename.
for example i have text.cpp on my desktop, i right click on it and there is a option called "Identify this file" then when the user chooses that the program will start.
also i want to input the filename as a variable automatic for example Sfilename value would become test.cpp!

I am not a professional, Please explain in easy language because i have searched a lot but what i had found was only bunch of explanations that i didn't understand.

My OS is WIndows 8 and i want to make it to work only on windows!

Comment: AFAIK, this requires "Shell extensions" - try googling for it, you should find several guides/tutorials.

Comment: What is being asked for does not require a Shell Extension. That is overkill. A simple Registry value added to the .cpp file extension registration handles this scenario just fine.

Comment: @KhashayarPourdeilami: I just posted an answer showing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an entry in the Windows context menu for files with a specific extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618977/how-to-add-an-entry-in-the-windows-context-menu-for-files-with-a-specific-extens)

Comment: It's clearly a real question, and the "dupe" doesn't ask "how do I do this" but "is this subkey why my code's not working?". Should be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

To add your application to the popup menu of files using a specific file extension, you can do the following:

1. Open/create the following Registry key:

   ```
   <root>\Software\Classes\<ext>
   ```

   Where `<root>` is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` if you want the menu item to appear only for the calling user and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` if you want it to appear for all users, and `<ext>` is the desired file extension (in this case, `.cpp`).
2. Read the `(Default)` value. If it does not exist, set it to a value of your choosing.
3. Open/create the following Registry key:

   ```
   <root>\Software\Classes\<progid>\Shell\<verb>
   ```

   Where `<progid>` is the value read in step #2, and `<verb>` is a unique value of your choosing for your app, eg: `OpenWithMyApp`.
4. Set its `(Default)` value to a description of what the menu item does, eg: `Open with my app`.
5. Create the following Registry key:

   ```
   <root>\Software\Classes\<progid>\Shell\<verb>\command
   ```
6. Set its `(Default)` value to the full path and command-line that you want to execute, where `%1` is placed where you want the selected file to appear, eg: `"c:\path to\myapp.exe" "%1"`

So, for example, it would look like this structure:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
  Software
    Classes
      .cpp
        (Default) = "CppFile"
      CppFile
        Shell
          OpenWithMyApp
            (Default) = "Open with my app"
            command
              (Default) = ""c:\path to\myapp.exe" "%1""
```

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148.aspx)

Comment: thank you! it worked me :) unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to vote this answer up! sorry :(

Comment: Oh i realized something what if i want it to work on every file extension?

Comment: Put your verb info underneath the `<root>\Software\Classes\*\shell` key instead of `<root>\Software\Classes\<progid>\shell` and ignore `<root>\Software\Classes\<ext>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a beginner topic, and the wording of your question suggests to me that you're just starting with Windows programming. There is [a starting point on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which may help you. You can't just Google for the code, you have to understand how Windows works. Specifically, you have to learn about the Shell, the name for the parts of Windows that make things work they way they do. When someone double-clicks a .docx file and Word loads, that's because Word registered itself as a handler for that extension. When someone right-clicks any file and "add to zip file" (or something similar) appears, that's because WinZip registered with the Shell to add that verb. You need to get a grasp of what these things are:

- the Shell
- a file extension (it's not just "the letters after the dot" it's a pile of registry entries and the like that associate those letters after the dot with an app)
- a registered handler for an extension
- a Verb (for the Shell)

The articles linked from the MSDN topic page I gave you will teach you what you need to know. But it's not simple. Even just knowing these words will help your searches. There are also [some samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=shell%20verb&f%5B0%5D.Value=shell%20verb&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=8) available, but don't try to start with those: read the background first.

Comment: Thank you, I will read those and i will try to figure it out! but do you have any solution for the file name input?

Comment: When you set up a handler or a verb the shell will give your code the file that was clicked on. You'll see.